# Add color to row or cell while creating excel through javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, colors, xlsx

Is there a way to add color to row or cell while creating excel through javascript?

I tried

```javascript
for (var k = 0; k < rowData.length; k++) {
        var cellValue = rowData[k];
        var cell = {
          v: cellValue,
          s: { fill: { fgColor: { rgb: "FFFF0000" } } }, 
        };
        rowData[k] = cell;
      }
```

But it didn't work
I need to change either background color of the row pr font color of the text in the row

Comment: Are you using a specific library to generate your spreadsheet?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Yes i added respective libraries:
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.18.0/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/xlsx/0.17.4/xlsx.full.min.js"></script>

The below is the code snippet
for (var k = 0; k < rowData.length; k++) {
        var cellValue = rowData[k];
        var cell = {
          v: cellValue,
          s: { fill: { fgColor: { rgb: "FFFF0000" } } }, // Red background color
        };
        rowData[k] = cell;
      }